# Are Mathematica and Matlab programming languages strictly speaking?

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I know both of them can be programmed. Are they programming languages strictly speaking and turing-complete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

If you don't like this answer provide accurate and precise definition of *programming language*.  *Turing complete* I'm OK with.

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB and Mathematica are [fourth-generation programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language).

You might be interested in seeing [these answers to a similar question about Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/24597) and also [this explanation](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Tour/MathematicaAsAProgrammingLanguage.html) by Wolfram about the ways in which Mathematica is a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

It is Wolfram language from now on, not Mathematica language.  References [here](http://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-language/) and [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/11/13/something-very-big-is-coming-our-most-important-technology-project-yet/) and [here](http://www.engadget.com/2013/11/14/wolfram-language/)

So, yes, the Wolfram language is a computer language.

Comment: Well, possibly.  Or possibly Wolfram Language will have the same impact on computation as A New Kind of Science had on science.